# Transfer possibly unsafe user input from hidden input field to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

The following is a simplified example of a page a user has created at a site (they created it by filling out a form and then they get a URL for the page; the below is the HTML for the page they created).

In the example, I'm taking the value of a hidden input field and then putting it into the DOM as is. That results in an alert, simulating an XSS attack.

What's the best way to prevent things like this? The value of #sourceinput was previously input by the same or a different user who's viewing the page below, and the user's input wasn't filtered to remove tags. (The actual case involves the jquery.tooltip.js plugin and it's bodyHandler callback; on mouseover a bodyHandler callback would get the hidden input and display it to the user.)

One way to deal with this would be to strip tags on input; I control what goes in the hidden textfield so that would seem to solve it.

Another way would be to strip tags in Javascript, but some of these don't seem to be 100% effective:

[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Is there some sort of best practice that I'm missing, or are those two the best ways?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var badHTML = $('#sourceinput').val();
  $('#destinationdiv').html( badHTML );
  //$('#destinationdiv').text( badHTML );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="sourceinput" value="&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;&#039;hi&#039;&#41;;&lt;/script&gt;" />
<div id="destinationdiv" style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: The solution I'm going with for now has three parts:

1. When the page the user has created is saved, I run PHP's strip_tags() on their input. These are just short text strings like titles and blurbs, so few users will expect they can enter HTML. That might not be appropriate for other situations.
2. When the page the user created is displayed, instead of putting what the user had entered in an input value attribute, I put their input inside a div.
3. I take the value out of that div using .text() (not .html() ). I then run that through the underscore function (see below).

Testing this out - including simulating skipping the first step - seems to work. At least I'm hoping there isn't something I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the escape function used by [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), if you don't want to use the entire Underscore library of functions:

```
var escape = function(string) {
    return (''+string).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#x27;').replace(/\//g,'&#x2F;');
};
```

Used like

```
var safe_html = escape("<b>Potentially unsafe text</b>"); // "&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"
$("#destination").html(safe_html);
```

It's written well and is known to work, so I'd advise against rolling your own.

Comment: be aware that that function only works between tags, not necessarily for html attributes, definitely not for javascript event handlers like onclick, in script tags or in css. See the OWASP xss prevention cheat sheet.

Comment: Clickable: [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you commented out (using text() from jquery is the better option). That will make sure the text stays text which is what you want. Filtering or stripping may have unwanted side effects like removing a mathematical expression in the input (" x is < 5").

Comment: My example is simplified, the concern arose because I'm using the jquery.tooltip.js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Do Nothing.

You are trying to protect the user *from himself*. There is no way the user A can harm user B. And for all you care, user A might as well type `javascript:alert('hi')` on the address bar and xss himself. And no matter what javascript escape function you create, a savvy user can always bypass it. All in all, its a pointless pursuit.

Now, if you start saving what the user entered on the server side, then you should definitely filter things. Don't build anything on your own. Depending on your server side language, there are several options. [OWASP's AntiSammy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_AntiSamy_Project) is one such solution.

If you do choose to save user entered html on the server side, make sure to run it by antisammy or a similar library *before saving it to the database*. On the way out, you should simply dump the HTML without escaping, because you know whatever is in the database is sanitized.

Comment: This is for a site that lets people create pages on the site, just like this one does. So, Bad Guy could put XSS in the page he's created and then Innocent User could view that page and get affected by it.